# Count date field that occurs in a specific month

Tags: excel, xcelsius

I need to count the occurrence of  a specified month in my data, I used the following formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(E$2:E$9999)=2)*(YEAR(E$2:E$9999)=2011)*1)
```

The formula works, but XCelsius do not recognize the SUMPRODUCT function

This is my data sample

```
2011/02/14  08:54:21 AM
2011/02/18  11:08:57 AM
2011/02/21  10:40:55 AM
2011/04/13  09:48:46 AM
2011/04/14  09:03:58 AM
2011/05/25  06:20:29 AM
```

Is there another way of counting the occurrences of a specified month

Comment: Which version of XCelsius are you using?

Comment: XCelsius Enterprise 5.5.0.0 || Build 12,5,0,1388

Comment: Thats interesting I used to have problems with the old builds but have never had problems with the new ones.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to use the SUMPRODUCT to do this, and will need to change to SUMIF or some another syntax. It seems SUMPRODUCT is very limited in XCelsius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

`=COUNTIF(E$2:E$9999,">=2011-02-01")-COUNTIF(E$2:E$9999,">=2011-03-01")`

Comment: I just used CONCATENATE function to ease the process, Thank you